# Unable to use CD/DVD drive after upgrade to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, cd

Just after my upgrade to Ubuntu 11.10 I can not use my cd/dvd drive.

The problem is that in Nautilus the CD/DVD icon appears ok, BUT, when I put any kind of media on the CD/DVD Driver, the icon vanishes and I can not mount (even by my self with pmount, mount, etc ) the driver.

Does anyone else have this strange behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using kernel 3.1 by a chance - downgarde it (for example to 3.0).
I had similar problem - I couldn't mount cdrom drive anyhow. Downgrading solved my problem and it works just fine!